# How can I parse different images into my table view reusable cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having troubles parsing images into my table view reusable cell. Hope anyone can help. Sorry if there is gonna be too many code, just don't want to miss something. Here is what my code look like:

```
import UIKit

struct OfferList: Decodable {
    let data: [CarItems]
    let status: String
    let count: Int }

struct CarItems: Decodable {

    let id: String
    let image: URL
    let manufacturer: String
    let model: String
    let priceNet: Double
    let priceOld: Int
    let priceGross: Double
    let powerKw: String
    let powerPs: String
    let milage: String
    let fueltype: String }

class OfferVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var viewModels = [CarItems]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let urlString = "http://grandex.de/api/v1/de/offers"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
            if let error = error { print(error); return }

            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                let result = try decoder.decode(OfferList.self, from: data!)
                self.viewModels = result.data
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
     }

extension OfferVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModels.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id") as! Cell
        let vm = viewModels[indexPath.row]
        cell.update(with: vm)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 130
    } }

class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var carImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var fueltype: UILabel!


    func update(with item: CarItems) {
        title?.text = item.manufacturer
        fueltype?.text = item.fueltype
        carImage?.image = item.image
    }

    func getImage(with item: CarItems){
        let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

        guard let url = URL(string: "\(item.image)") else { return }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print("Something went wrong: \(error)")
            }

            if let imageData = data {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.carImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    } }
```

I'm expecting it to add images to my cells, but it doesn't work. 
Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: "but it doesn't work": Is `self.carImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)` even called? What's wrong exactly? What about using AlamofireImage, SDWebImage, KingFisher, etc? They do it very well.

Comment: By "It doesn't work", did you mean that your images are constantly getting shuffled as you scroll? That would be because you did not cache them.

Comment: And where are you calling the getImage method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in `CarItems` `struct`, set the type of `image` as `String` instead of `URL`. You get a `String` from `JSON` and not a `URL` type.

In `update(with:)` method, call `getImage(with:)` method, i.e.

```
func update(with item: CarItems) {
    title?.text = item.manufacturer
    fueltype?.text = item.fueltype
    self.getImage(with: item) //Here..
}
```

Also, keep the code as short as possible. You can cut down the `getImage(with:)` method to:

```
func getImage(with item: CarItems){
    guard let url = URL(string: "\(item.image)") else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {[weak self] (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.carImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, PGDev! Now it works fine!
One question though: is it ok that it takes a while to load these images? Or it's always like that in a simulator?

Comment: @СерафимКовальчук Use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) or [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

Comment: @RajeshKumarR We shouldn't use 3rd party libraries until it is required. `SDWebImage` and `Kingfisher` are great libraries, but I don't think there is any specific requirement for this use case. Adding 3rd parties unnecessarily only increases the project size.

Comment: update method is called in cellForRow method. If we scroll the tableview repeatedly It calls the api repeatedly. By caching the image data in local it is avoided. After this, it won't call api multiple times for the same url/image